# social blog Like button

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Like button is not working. here is my code please check
it gives error
Cannot assign "'3'": "LikePost.post_id" must be a "Post" instance.

view.py

```
def like_post(request):
    user_id = request.user.username
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    like_filter = LikePost.objects.filter(post_id=post_id,username=user_id).first()

    if like_filter == None:
        new_like = LikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id, username=user_id)
        new_like.save()
        post.no_of_likes = post.no_of_likes+1
        post.save()
        return redirect('showpost.html')
    else:
        like_filter.delete()
        post.no_of_likes = post.no_of_likes-1
        post.save()
        return redirect('showpost.html')
```

model.py

```
class LikePost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

HTML FILE:

```
<div class="flex space-x-4 lg:font-bold col-lg-6 d-flex flex-wrap mt-2">
   <a href="/like-post?post_id={{post.id}}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
      <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black  d-flex">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="25" height="25" class="">
         <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
       </svg>
    {% if post.no_of_likes == 0 %}
     <p class="mb-0">No likes</p>
    {% elif post.no_of_likes == 1 %}
    <p>Liked by {{post.no_of_likes}} person</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Liked by {{post.no_of_likes}} people</p>
    {% endif %}
     </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `request.user.username` is presumably a string and not an ID, which is why you are getting an error. Use `request.user.pk`

Comment: its not working, it gives same error

Comment: Oh, it's because you don't have a field called `username` so you need to change that to a field that exists on the model, such as `user_id` etc. the error tells you which are possible

Comment: one times i hit on like button it like but again i hit on like button it gives that error                            
           Cannot assign "'1'": "LikePost.post_id" must be a "Post" instance.

Comment: Try `post_id_id` - you have made things more confusing because your foreign key fields have `_id` in them. "'1'" is just a string but Django expects an instance, so you need to either give it an instance or tell Django that you're entering the string ID

Answer (score 0):

```
user_id = User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk)
```

Get the object and pass it in to create a query it will work,Because ForeignKey accept object intend of id or any value

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change your `likefilter` as currently you're trying to retrieve a `LikePost` with `post_id` and `user_id` attributes. You should have something like:

```
like_filter = LikePost.objects.filter(post_id=post_id,user_id=user_id).first()
```

And I may be wrong but it seems like your `user_id` contains the username value of your user instead of its id, so you could also change that to:

```
user_id = request.user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_id = request.user.pk
like_filter = LikePost.objects.filter(post_id=post_id, pk=user_id).first()
```

try this way